# iExpress error: "Unable to end update of resources"

Tags: iexpress

I've been successfully using iExpress for years.  Now, when generating the same .exe files that I always generate, iExpress is now giving me the error: Unable to end update of resources.

This error comes at the very end of the process.  I see the Create Package screen and the text "Creating the package..."   Then the error occurs.  In the file folder, I'll see a file like: ~MyFileName.CAB which would normally be deleted at the end of running iExpress.

I've tried deleting the .CAB file and rerunning iExpress again (many times).  I tried rebooting.  I tried running iExpress with different applications.  I tried searching the web and Stack Overflow.  I'm using the same Windows user account I normally use.  Desperate for help as I'm unable to release my applications.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved, though not exactly sure how.  I did have another user run iExpress on my machine as that other user.  (Ie, right-click on the iExpress executable and run as the other user.)  That user was able to run iExpress without the error I reported above.  And after that, iExpress started magically working for me too.

Could running as the other user have caused Windows to clear out some file that had been corrupted?  Something else?  I don't know.  I just thought I would write what happened in case this can help someone else in the future.

---

FURTHER UPDATE
The problem popped up again.  I finally figured out that if I closed File Explorer before running iExpress, the error never happens.  There's some bug with Windows 10 and/or iExpress where having the folder open can interfere with the final step that iExpress does.

Of interest:  It's not a consistent bug.  Sometimes iExpress finished and sometimes I got the above error when File Explorer and the folder in question was open.